# Sqlite file has data in it that is not showing up in tables

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite file which contains data in the raw file that does not show up in the tables when I load the file. How is this possible, and is there a way to load the data into a table that can be queried?

Steps taken:

1. opened file in a GUI app, browsed the data
2. looked at the tail of the file in my terminal, noticed data I didn't see in the GUI app
3. loaded the file in `sqlite3` and inspected the tables, same data as the GUI app
4. Checked the file type with `file` command which confirmed it is a sqlite file v3

Comment: A sqlite database is not human readable... using tail, etc. to try to read it isn't going to work very well.

Comment: you may also see deleted data (old pages not yet reused or vacuumed)